# How to Set WebBrowser.DocumentType

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

How can we set WebBrowser.DocumentType ?

Answer (score 0):

The DocumentType property only reflects the documenttype of the current document.

You'll have to modify the content of the web browser through the Document or DocumentText property.

Having checked it, the property actually only contains a rather uninteresting text description like "Text Document" or "JPEG Image". Possibly not what you're after anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating a temporary file, setting an appropriate file extension on that file, then loading that file.  It seems like there should be an easier way, but this worked for me.

```
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xml";
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, xmlTextBox.Text);
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(fileName);
            // The following seems like it would work, but the document type is wrong.  Typically
            // the window looks blank, but when you right click and ask it to show source, you
            // see the XML code.
            //webBrowser1.DocumentText = xmlTextBox.Text;
```